# Why do my https requests hang for several minutes?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, https, expo

I make https request from a react native app. Sometimes the requests hang for about 2 minutes (no reject, no resolve). Here are some symptoms:

- It looks like it happens only on some network (4G works, wifi doesn't)
- It comes and goes (can work 100 times, then stop working)
- looks like https fails when http succeeds
- The same requests work perfectly in Chrome (same device, same network)
- I use react native with expo
- tried fetch & axios

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

You can try axios or fetch with some timeout value and can verify if you are getting timeout error this means request not gettng fulfilled within defined time and there can be plenty of reasons not specific to react-native.

Sometime with simulator/virtual devices we face issue like network calls not working properly due to low memory configuration or other network related issues.
You can also try to reproduce same in real device and relase version.

Comment: Thank for the answer I'll add a retry mechanism, but the hanging requests looks too schematic. No matter how many times I try, requests will hang for minutes.. When I try a different network it works, and when I try the same requests from chrome it works, only from my app (release version on a real device) on some networks it hangs.

Comment: @Diamant did you manage to find the solution? I also have this problem with expo + axios on 4G!

Comment: @SkyPower unfortunately no..

Comment: @Diamant in my case it turned out that a bad initialization of socket.io was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Some of our users have seen this in production on certain cell networks. The phone thinks it has a valid cell connection, but no data can be sent because the tower is no longer in range. Normally the cell phone should recognize when the connection isn't functioning and reconnect to a different cell tower automatically, but that doesn't always happen.

This may depend on the device with Android being more varied and possibly more unreliable than iOS in detecting and reconnecting in these scenarios. It may also depend on the geographic location and the cell coverage density.

We set a 10-second connection timeout on requests and if the promise hasn't resolved, show a banner to the user advising them to refresh the network connection. With Axios, you can set a connection timeout using `AbortController` in a helper function as shown [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation).

```js
function newAbortSignal(timeoutMs) {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), timeoutMs || 0);

  return abortController.signal;
}

axios.get('/foo/bar', {
   signal: newAbortSignal(5000) //Aborts request after 5 seconds
}).then(function(response) {
   //...
});
```